# New terminal with command and continue using it

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

I would like to open a new terminal and run a command from another terminal. I would like to be able to re-use that terminal after.

I've tried:

```
xfce4-terminal --hold -x echo "Hello" &
```

But while `--hold` does keep the new window open, it's "blocked" and can't be used. Is there a way around this?

(I'd use either Gnome or XFCE terminals)